# Building equilateral triangles by reflecting tokens

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, geometry

Three tokens are placed at the vertices of an equilateral triangle with side length 1.
A move is to reflect a token at any other token. After several moves the tokens build again an equilateral triangle.

Which side lengths are possible for this new triangle?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The possible side lengths are

> just 1 unit.

And here's why:

> Imagine a triangular grid:
>  [image: triangular grid with tokens on three adjacent vertices]
>  No matter how many times you reflect, your tokens will always be on the vertices of this grid. So you can't make any *smaller* equilateral triangles.
>
>  But what about bigger ones? Well, all moves are reversible. So if you made a bigger equilateral triangle, you could just undo those moves to shrink your triangle back to one unit. And if *that* were possible, you could shrink your size-1 triangle by performing the same moves!
>
>  So you can't shrink *or* grow your triangle; the only possible equilateral triangle has side length 1.

Comment: Nice and clean proof. I like the reversibility argument. Good one!

Comment: I don't get it. If I "reflect" B on A, but leave C where it is, won't I get a triangle with sides 1,1, and (2 times equilateral height)?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis: It's not "again an **equilateral** triangle".

Comment: Not to be a party pooper, but are you sure the symmetry argument works? Assume that getting from a side-1 triangle to a side-2 triangle is possible by using reflections on the side-1 grid. By symmetry, getting from a side-2 triangle to a side-1 triangle is possible by using reflections on the side-1 grid. By similarity, this means getting from a side-1 triangle to a side-0.5 triangle is possible by using reflections *on a side-0.5 grid*. Does that necessarily contradict the fact that it's not possible by using reflections on the side-1 grid?

Comment: @Randal'Thor: The reflections aren't relative to any particular grid. The grid arises from the properties of the reflections. Drawing a different grid doesn't change the possible reflections.

Answer (score 20):

Alternate answer:

> It can only have a side length of 1.

> Consider any reflection where A is reflected across B to A'.  Before, the area is (AB)*(height).  After, the area is (A'B)*(height').  The reflection keeps (AB) = (A'B), and the two heights are the same, so the area remains the same.

> Therefore, only triangles with area equal to that of the original triangle can be formed, and the only equilateral triangle with that area is a congruent one.

Comment: Not an "alternate" answer IMO but rather *the* answer.